# Accessing a server directory

Tags: command-line, networking, server, mount

At my university, I have a home directory located on the main university server. To access this directory, I have been given some instructions which will mount the server on my local machine, and create a directory on my machine which is symbolic link to my home directory on the server. These instructions are:

```
sudo mount.cifs //{server.university.extension} {path_to_local_directory} -o username={username},password={password},domain={domain},uid={username}
```

Whilst I do not fully understand the above, when I replace the information inside the curly brackets with the required information, this works and creates a local directory which I can use to access the network directory.

However, what I actually want to do, is to access that directory from the command line. One way of doing this would be to navigate to my local directory, and act as if that was the network directory. But this seems a little inefficient. So is there a way to connect directly to the server directory, without mounting it on my local machine?

Comment: mounting the directory as you have been told will give you the fastest and most versatile access to your files. What might interest you is to automount the directory whenever you refer to it, and auto-unmount it when you are no longer using it. Search for the topic and the version/flavour of ubuntu you use for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The method you described where you access the local directory is **the** way that samba facilitates network access.

Keep in mind that in linux, everything is a file of some sort. Even your cpu and ram have "files" under /dev.